# Running Simple Java Program on Amazon Cloud

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am trying out Amazon cloud as I have quite a computationally-intensive simulation I would like to run.

As I test, I created a simple class Test.java

```
package test;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("TEST");

    }

}
```

In Eclipse, I set the compiler to JVM 1.6 for compliance reasons. I retrieved the class file from the /bin directory of the project and copied it via SSH to the root of my CloudServer.

I then tried:

```
java Test
```

and

```
java -cp . test
```

Which return

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: java
```

I am unsure how to continue from here... All I would expect is TEST to be output to console...

Comment: did you copy the file to a folder named test, because your class is in the package test

Comment: @Sanj I have now, and I get: Error: Could not find or load main class Test

Comment: when I run the command from within Test: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Test (wrong name: test/Test)

Comment: try java -cp . test.Test

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassFormatError: Extra bytes at the end of class file test/Test
...What?

Comment: oooh winscp was transferring in text rather than binary. Fixed! :)

Comment: sorry no idea what that error is? Could you have copied across wrong? ftping in text rather than binary?